# Change the size of an image when Click

Tags: jquery, image, resize, onclick, image-gallery

I'm trying to make an image become bigger with a black-background in the back overflowing the content (just like a normal image gallery) anyway I have failed to achieve the results after days of attempts.

However, I'm now trying to make the image bigger On Click, and go to the normal size when Hover-away. Is there anyway I can do so with JQ? I am not sure that I can do it with CSS.

Please take a look at the site and code that I am using at this moment: http://www.webdesignstudents.co.uk/students/loai_shehadeh/visual-identity.html

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about a modal-popup?  Like this...http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Comment: I was trying to make something like this (but very basic).
http://tympanus.net/Development/GammaGallery/

Please try to click on an image and see how it become bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class on your element:

```
<img src="img/image.jpg" class=imggallery>
```

Then on your css add something like this:

```
imggallery {width:60%;height:auto;}
imggallery:hover {width:90%;height:auto;}
imggallery:active  {width:100%;height:auto;}
```

Or you can try a small gallery like this one http://www.minigal.dk/minigal-nano.html

Comment: Thank you, I like rather making it my self to use a plugin.
Your method is working, but there is small problem.
I have 3 columns on there, that's how I got that view, the reason why I have columns and not making the images float, is because the images width is different and I want them to float to fill the spaces and just go to the top rather keeping white space... 

Do you think I can do something to get ride of the column or somthing? Thanks lot!

Comment: Hi i am not sure without look at your code but if you just need to display the image on another position use css positioning:

[code]imggallery:hover {width:90%;height:auto;margin:-500 0 0 200;padding:30 30 30 30}[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin, it should do what you want and with more options than what you can do in the same time it takes to implement it yourself :) http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

Might wanna try fancybox for this...

http://fancybox.net/

Or lightbox...

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/